# How do I find the Tenant ID of my SharePoint Online Account using SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to get `Tenant Id` of my SharePoint online site using SPFX.

Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO, Finally i got the solution for that.
For that you have to call API and i.e.
    https://**your_site**.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc.

I am providing the function to get TenantID.

```
static getTenant() {

const request = new Request('https://{your_site}.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'bearer'
  })
});
return fetch(request).then(response => {
  var data = response.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate').split(',');
  return data;
  }).catch(error => {
  return error;
});
}
```

You will get the Bearer realm component and that's your tenant ID.

or you can get it by other way.

Follow the article to get TenantID i.e

http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2016/01/azure-active-directory-get-tenant-id.html

Answer (score 0):

SPFx components contain the current tenant id information in the context object as well:

`this.context.pageContext.aadInfo.tenantId._guid`